# How to reference unique entries over different subsites and different groups?

Tags: localization, relations, language, multi-domain

We're investigating the use of headless CMSs for a health care and revalidation company. The website should consist of multiple subsites (specialized groups) which each have multiple localized content (translated entries). Our ideal structure would be the following:

- Main group (maindomain.com): EN website entries, NL website entries
- Specialized group 1 (domain1.maindomain.com): EN website entries, NL website entries
- Specialized group 2 (domain2.maindomain.com): EN, NL
- Specialized group x (domainx.maindomain.com): EN, NL

We're encountering the following problems though:

**Problem 1**: We'd like to create entries for a selection of groups, say a contact page, and share it between multiple groups. We're aware entries can propagate over same language subsites only but the problem is that the entry is created as a duplicate over the provided subsites, meaning: if we modify the contact page entry in the main group NL subsite, it is not updated on the contact page entry in the specialized groups.

**Problem 2**: We'd also like to add links/references to an entry for creating links to other subsite's entries on a page. However, no entries from a different subsite are visible when trying to add to another subsite entry in the backend.

What would be the ideal structure for this to make this work? Would Craft be ideal to use for this structure at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multi-site and translation settings in Craft are very flexible, so it can be used for different kinds of content syndication requirements. The two main levers are as follows:

- [Section settings](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#sections), in particular [propagation settings](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/sites.html#propagating-entries-across-all-enabled-sites)
- [Translation methods](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/fields.html#translation-methods) for individual fields

By combining those settings in different way, you can create a lot of different workflows. This is difficult to plan out completely in theory, it's easier to give it a try and experiment with different settings to achieve your intended editorial workflow.

If any specific requirement can't be solved with those options, you still have a lot of control through the output layer (frontend templates) and you can use [event hooks](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/events.html) to modify the propagation and translation behaviour.

> **Problem 1**: We'd like to create entries for a selection of groups, say a contact page, and share it between multiple groups. We're aware entries can propagate over same language subsites only but the problem is that the entry is created as a duplicate over the provided subsites, meaning: if we modify the contact page entry in the main group NL subsite, it is not updated on the contact page entry in the specialized groups.

You have multiple options here. If you propagate entries across all sites, you can still set the [translation method](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/fields.html#translation-methods) for the fields on this entry in a way that will copy entry content across specific sites. For example, you can put two sites that should share entry content in a single website group and set the fields inside the entry to `Translate for each site group`. This way, editing an entry for one of the two sites will copy any changes over to the other one.

Another option is to *not* propagate entries and only activate the section for a subset of sites. A section that's only active for one a specific site can still be used as a source of content for other sites. Use the `site` query parameter on element queries to fetch content from a specific site (the default is to only fetch content from the *current* site).

> **Problem 2:** We'd also like to add links/references to an entry for creating links to other subsite's entries on a page. However, no entries from a different subsite are visible when trying to add to another subsite entry in the backend.

Are you talking about [Entries fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries-fields.html#settings)? In this case, you just need to check `Show the site menu` under the `Advanced` section of the field settings. This will allow you to select related entries across sites. There are also a couple of other related settings there that might be useful, so be sure to check those thoroughly.